# Sum of nested JSON array using D3 .rollup

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to get the sum and average of each key in a nested array of objects that looks as follows:

```
    var data = [
    {department:'Electro',quant:{M:30, T:20, W:51, R:22, F:35 }},
    {department:'Beauty'',quant:{M:50, T:32, W:75, R:61, F: 45}},
    {department:'Apparel'',quant:{M:62, T:42, W:135, R: 82, F:89}},
    {department:'Misc',quant:{M:89, T:54, W:103, T:94, F:90}}
];
```

So I would need the sum of each department separately. i.e sum = { 'Elecro': 158, 'Beauty': 263}

I am using the rollup method but the [examples](http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html) aren't for nested arrays.

```
var deptSum = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.dept; })
.rollup(function(v) { return {
    count: v.length,
    total: d3.sum(v, function(d) {return d.quant; }),
    avg: d3.mean(v, function(d) {return d.quant; })
}; })
.entries(data)
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(deptSum))

But is giving me 0's for the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a D3 method to get the sum (and the average as well) inside the rollup. The problem, however, is that both `d3.sum` and `d3.mean` expect an **array**, but `quant` is just an object:

```
quant: {M:30, T:20, W:51, R:22, F:35 };
```

**Solution**: use the D3 method to get the property values, called `d3.values`. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#values), it:

> Returns an array containing the property values of the specified object (an associative array).

Thus, your `rollup` should be:

```
.rollup(function(v) {
    return {
        count: v.length,
        total: d3.sum(d3.values(v[0].quant)),
        avg: d3.mean(d3.values(v[0].quant))
    };
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [
    {department:'Electro',quant:{M:30, T:20, W:51, R:22, F:35 }},
    {department:'Beauty',quant:{M:50, T:32, W:75, R:61, F: 45}},
    {department:'Apparel',quant:{M:62, T:42, W:135, R: 82, F:89}},
    {department:'Misc',quant:{M:89, T:54, W:103, T:94, F:90}}
];

var deptSum = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.department; })
.rollup(function(v) { return {
    count: v.length,
    total: d3.sum(d3.values(v[0].quant)),
    avg: d3.mean(d3.values(v[0].quant))
}; })
.entries(data)

console.log(deptSum)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need d3 for that, here is a pure js solution :

```
var sumData = data.map(function(d) {
   var sum = Object.values(d.quant).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
   return { department: d.department, sum: sum}
}).reduce(function(result, item) {
  result[item.department] = item.sum;
  return result;
}, {})
```

will give you `{"Electro":158,"Beauty":263,"Apparel":410,"Misc":376}`

See https://jsfiddle.net/96msy7jd/1

Comment: This works too, but it would seem that the D3 methods could produce it with less code to get other stats for the nested array like mean, count, etc. I can be wrong.